# Angular 5 HTTP request in guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httprequest, guard

I'm trying to call an http GET request in a guard. It's not working maybe because of synchronisation... I'm basically getting links which are access permissions with ids for the logged user. What am i doing wrong?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { LinkService } from '../services/link.service';



@Injectable()
export class ManageProjectUsersGuard implements CanActivate {
links: any[] = [];

constructor(
    private auth: AppService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private linkService: LinkService
) { }

canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {


    var selectedProject = this.authService.getProjectIdFromUrl(state.url);
    if (!selectedProject) {
        selectedProject = this.authService.getSelectedProject();
    }
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    if (!user || !user.username || !selectedProject) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.linkService.getLinksByUsername(user.username).map((links) => {
        this.links = links;
        console.log(this.links)
        var flag = false

        for (let i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) {
            if (this.links[i].project.id == selectedProject && this.links[i].user.username == user.username) {
                if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.links[i])).role.id == 2) {

                    flag = true;
                    return flag; // access allowed
                }
            }
        }
        return flag; // access denied
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what the exact problem is or create a minimal working example e.g. as a stackblitz? What do you mean by it's not working because of synchronisation? If the route is loading forever, for example, than your observable is not completing - then you would have to add a take(1) after your map. But that's just a random guess, not knowing what your actual error is.

Comment: In addition, could you show use the exact error from developer tools?

Comment: it's printing information correctly. No error is displayed! It's not loading the requested page! Maybe because I'm returning true/false inside a return... @Erbsenkoenig

Comment: If it's not loading I would think, that your observable is not completing, please add a take(1) after mapping the observable returned from getLinksByUsername with this you are ensuring, that the observable completes after the first emitted value.

Comment: like this? this.linkService.getLinksByUsername(user.username).take(1).map((links) => { @Erbsenkoenig

Comment: After the mapping: ```this.linkService.getLinksByUsername(...).map(...).take(1)```

Comment: The return value inside guard have to be consistent. Either you return all boolean or return all as Observable<boolean>. 
Change all the place with `return false` or `true`. to `return of(false)` or `return of(true)`.